How to write a ctor for a class owning nocopy-nomove types of which one is to be init.ed from another one that can be one out of several types?
I start from a scenario like this:

the non-copiable-nor-movable classes Foo1, Foo2, and Baz are untouchable
struct Foo1 { Foo1(int); Foo1(Foo1&&) = delete; }; // I can't touch it
struct Foo2 { Foo2(int); Foo2(Foo2&&) = delete; }; // I can't touch it
struct Baz { Baz(Foo1&); Baz(Foo2&); Baz(Baz&&) = delete; }; // I can't touch it


a fourth class, Bar, I have control of, looks initially like this:
struct Bar {
    Bar(int i)
        : i{i}
        , foo{i}
        , baz{foo}
    {}
    int i;
    Foo1 foo;
    Baz baz;
};



At a later point, the need arises that Bar::foo be actually either a Foo1 or a Foo2 depending on the i fed to Bar's constructor.
My initial thought was to use a std::variant, but changing Bar to fulfil the new requirement is not entirely straightforward, because the non-copiable-nor-movable-ity of Foo1, Foo2, and Baz, gets in the way:

changing Foo1 foo; to std::variant<Foo1, Foo2> foo; causes in the initialization foo{i} to fail to compile, and that's normal, but let's also simplify things by saying that for now we're still only putting a Foo1 in foo, by changing also foo{i} to foo{Foo1{i}}; this still doesn't work because of the non-movability of Foo1;
so I think, ok, I need to construct the Foo1 in place in the std::variant; this would be viable, if Bar did not have a Baz member, because I could make the std::variant default constructible by including std::monostate in it (and this would also allow the conditional construction of Foo1 or Foo2:
struct Bar {
    Bar(int i)
        : i{i}
        //, baz{foo}
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            foo.emplace<Foo1>(i);
        } else {
            foo.emplace<Foo2>(i);
        }
    }
    int i;
    std::variant<std::monostate, Foo1, Foo2> foo{};
    //Baz baz;
};



The above observations lead me to think that a solution could be using std::unique_ptr, but it does too require quite a bit of code, because one must std::visit in order to construct Baz:
struct Bar {
    using Var = std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Foo1>, std::unique_ptr<Foo2>>;
    Bar(int i)
        : i{i}
        , foo{i == 0 ? Var{std::make_unique<Foo1>(i)} : Var{std::make_unique<Foo2>(i)}}
        , baz{std::visit([](auto&& p) { return Baz{*p}; }, foo)}
    {}
    int i;
    Var foo;
    Baz baz;
};

I was wondering if I have missed some cleaner way to deal with such a scenario.

Do Foo1 and Foo2 have anything in common that Bar needs to do with it? E.g. is the functionality representable by an abstract baseclass? If so I have an idea

@PepijnKramer, I can't edit Foo1 and Foo2 in any way, not even adding a base class to them. Anyway, they do have something in common, but it's not code I'm familiar with, so it's not easy to know how much; from my standpoint, what they have in common is that they can both be used to produce a Baz.

Something must use Foo1, or Foo2 later and I am curious what that use is. Are they just data holders or something that is acted on?

@PepijnKramer, it's that Baz's ctor takes Foo1 or Foo2 by reference, and uses them  and expects them to stay alive, so I have to keep them alive too, in Var. In there (I mean, in Foo1 and Foo2) is mad code I'm not familiar with.

You can construct the variant in place, no need of std::monostate:
struct Bar {
    using Foo = std::variant<Foo1, Foo2>;
    Bar(int i)
        : i{i}
        , foo{i == 0 ? Foo(std::in_place_type<Foo1>, i) : Foo(std::in_place_type<Foo2>, i)}
        , baz{std::visit([](auto&& p) { return Baz{p}; }, foo)}
    {}
    int i;
    std::variant<Foo1, Foo2> foo;
    Baz baz;
};

Demo
Unfortunately, msvc rejects that code, but using intermediate function (as lambda) works :
struct Bar {
    using Foo = std::variant<Foo1, Foo2>;
    Bar(int i)
        : i{i}
        , foo{[](int i){
            if (i == 0) {
                return Foo(std::in_place_type<Foo1>, i);
            } else {
                return Foo(std::in_place_type<Foo2>, i);
            }
        }(i)}
        , baz{std::visit([](auto&& p) { return Baz{p}; }, foo)}
    {}
    int i;
    std::variant<Foo1, Foo2> foo;
    Baz baz;
};

Demo
